# Cannot get data-id or value of lightning-input in @api Method in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, queryselector

I'm trying to call Child method from Parent as shown below. When I try to get data-id or value of lightning-input I get undefined.

Parent.html

```html
            <template for:each={tabFieldConfig} for:item="tab">
                <template if:false={tab.isCustom}>
                    <lightning-tab value={tab.tabName} label={tab.tabName} key={tab.tabName} onactive={handleActiveTab}>
                        <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters">
                            <div class="slds-col slds-size_5-of-12">
                                <c-skip-trace-content-component tabfields={tab.fieldInformation} skip-trace-type={skipTraceType}></c-skip-trace-content-component>
                            </div>
                            <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-12">
                                <div class="centerOfGrid" data-aura-rendered-by="161:1812;a"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="slds-col slds-size_6-of-12">
                                <c-skip-trace-show-bulk-data skip-trace-data={skipTraceData} onshowselectedresult={handleSelectResult}></c-skip-trace-show-bulk-data>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <template if:true={showButtons}>
                            <div class="slds-align_absolute-center" style="padding-top: 5%;">
                                <template for:each={tab.tabButtons} for:item="button">
                                    <lightning-button variant={button.Variant__c} data-id={button.DeveloperName} label={button.Button_Label__c} style="padding-right: 2%;" key={button.DeveloperName} onclick={handleButtonClick}></lightning-button>
                                </template>
                            </div>
                        </template>
                    </lightning-tab>
                </template>
                <template if:true={tab.isCustom}>
                    <lightning-tab label={tab.tabName} key={tab.tabName}>
                        <c-skip-trace-bulk-component></c-skip-trace-bulk-component>
                    </lightning-tab>
                </template>
            </template>
```

Parent.js

```js
    handleButtonClick(event) {
        this.template.querySelector("c-skip-trace-content-component").handleInputValues();
    }
```

Child.html

```html
    <template for:each={tabfields} for:item="fields">
        <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters" key={fields.DeveloperName}>
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-1">
                <template if:false={fields.Is_Address_Field__c}>
                    <template if:false={fields.Is_File_Upload__c}>
                        <lightning-input name={fields.API_Field_Name__c} data-id={fields.API_Field_Name__c} style="padding-left: 3%; padding-right:3%;" label={fields.Field_Label__c} type={fields.Field_Type__c} key={fields.Field_Label__c} onchange={handleInputValues}></lightning-input>
                    </template>
                </template>
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>
```

Child.Js

```js
@api
handleInputValues() {

    let inputFields = this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input');
    inputFields.forEach(element => {

        // I have tried all these ways
        console.log(element.currentTarget.dataset.id);
        console.log(element.target.dataset.id);
        console.log(element.dataset.id);
    });
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `API_Field_Name__c` is not null? Also, loop variables should be singular, generally (`field` rather than `fields`).

Comment: I'm dynamically creating the Fields, Field properties are stored in custom meta data and according to that fields are being populate. **YES, I'm sure that  API_Field_Name__c is not Null**

Comment: But a single instance still represents a single field, no?

Comment: No, Single instance represent all fields

Comment: We need to see more code for context. Your comments imply that multiple components are involved. The number one rule to remember is that a parent component sees its child components as "black boxes", meaning you can't query elements inside of the child component directly. This is referred to as the "Shadow DOM" model of web components. Can you [edit] your question to include all the relevant code?

Comment: **I have updated my Question with code for parent and Child components** @sfdcfox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just Figured out the issue.

As I'm calling the child component in Loop so There will be more than 1 child component.
So for example I have 3 section that needs to display it means 1 parent and 3 child. So to call the respective child's method I need to get specific that child and then call its public @api method.

So following line of code needs to be change. In case of 3 child, I need to call 2nd child's method. I will call like this.

```js
this.template.querySelectorAll("c-skip-trace-content-component")[1].handleInputValues();
```